# How to add a convolutional layer in the shortcut connection using functional API in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[image: Custom model]

I am trying to implement a custom CNN model like the one shown in the attached figure using the functional API in Keras. I have written the code to implement the main branch but having issues in adding the 1x1 convolutions as a shortcut connection. The shortcut convolution is added for each pair of convolution blocks, just before the max-pooling layer. The code is given below:

```
input_shape = (256,256,3)
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
print(model_input) 

def custom_cnn(model_input):
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (2,2), padding = 'same')(model_input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (2,2), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(80, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(80, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
            
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x, name='custom_cnn')
    return model

#instantiate the model
custom_model = custom_cnn(model_input)

#display model summary
custom_model.summary()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the implementation of the residual blocks inside your network following the schema:

[image]

```
num_classes = 3
input_shape = (256,256,3)
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

def custom_cnn(model_input):
    
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (2,2), padding = 'same')(model_input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (2,2), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    xx = Conv2D(16, (1,1), strides= (4,4), padding = 'same')(model_input)
    x = Add()([x,xx])
    xx = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    xx = Conv2D(32, (1,1), strides= (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = Add()([x,xx])
    xx = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    xx = Conv2D(48, (1,1), strides= (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = Add()([x,xx])
    xx = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    xx = Conv2D(64, (1,1), strides= (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = Add()([x,xx])
    xx = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(80, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(80, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    xx = Conv2D(80, (1,1), strides= (1,1), padding = 'same')(xx)
    x = Add()([x,xx])
    xx = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
            
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(xx)
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x, name='custom_cnn')
    return model

#instantiate the model
custom_model = custom_cnn(model_input)

#display model summary
custom_model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge multiple layers with `keras.layers.concatenate` function so if you have 2 "parallel" layers `x` and `y`, you can do merge them into layer `z` like this:

```
z = layers.concatenate([x, y])
```

In your code, it would look something like this:

First, create the one "parallel" layer (note that both layers `x` and later `y` will be applied on the same layer starting with the `model_input` layer)

```
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (2,2), padding = 'same')(model_input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (2,2), padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
```

Then you would create the second "parallel" layer:

```
y = Conv2D(...)(model_input)
```

Merge them

```
z = layers.concatenate([x, y])
```

and apply max pooling on the `z` (on the layer that is the result of the concatenation)

```
z = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(z)
```

And again, create two branches, both taking `z` as an input (where `z` is equivalent to the `model_input` from the previous iteration) and repeat for each of these blocks where you need to apply concatenation.

Comment: Thanks but It throws an error after the first concatenation: ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 8, 8, 32), (None, 31, 31, 32)] because of issues with concatenation with different input dimensions. The authors have their tensorflow code at https://github.com/frapa/tbcnn/blob/master/net.py but i have issues converting them to Keras compatible code.

Comment: That is because dimensions of the layers that you want to concatenate must be the same except for the axis on which you are performing the concatenation. You can specify which axis you want to concatenate on but the rest must match which is not the case with your output where 2 of the dimensions do not match (8 != 31 and 8 != 31)